# Solving for functions $f$ and $g$

Tags: functions, derivatives

There is a problem I'm working on that has stumped me a bit at this point. 
Here is where I'm struggling.
My goal is to find the two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.  What I have is this

$f(x)+g(x)=0, x\geq 0$

$f'(x)-g'(x)=0, x\geq 0$

$h(x)=f(ax)+g(-ax), x\geq 0$

We can assume $h$ and $a$ to be known (I don't mind to have $f$ and $g$ solved in terms of $h$ and $a$).

Whenever I try to solve the problem i get $f$ and $g$ to be constants which makes no sense for my big problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If $f(x) = -g(x)$ and $f'(x) = g'(x)$ then the only solution is that $f$ and $g$ are indeed both constants.

Answer (score 0):

Integrating the second expression, we find $f(x)-g(x)$ is constant for $x>0$. Combining this with the first expression, we get $f(x)=c=-g(x)$ for some constant $c$. If this doesn't make sense for your problem then you have made an error earlier on!

Comment: I must've made an error!  I'll add a bit more detail then now.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking of the edited portion of your post, only.
You gave the initial condition of a .. "string at rest" and that at time $t=0$ has its extreme at $x=0$ that starts and move according  to $b(t)$.
Ok, but you simply forgot .. **the string**. I mean, you did not give the constitutional laws of the string (mass, elasticity, ..) which are those that will propagate the motion of the end to the rest of the string.